# Timeline app logo image

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

This is probably a basic function I need to change but, when I upload a logo for the main app image with the new timeline (111x74) it renders in view as about half that size.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the timeline where the app is installed. Then on right of the tabs you have a little pointing down arrow, click on it. After you will see a little pencil when you mouse is over your apps. Click on the pencil of the app from which you want to change the the logo then click Edit settings and change custom tab image.

[image: Step1][image: Step2]